# Encryption algorithm for 14 byte data

Tags: c, security, encryption

I have an application, where I have to transfer an encrypted packet over BLE advertisement which is fixed 14 byte in length. AES algorithm restricts data to be minimum of 16 bytes long and DES requires it to be in multiples of 8 byte. I have a odd length of 14 byte which I cannot change. Is there any encryption algorithm which can be used to encrypt this 14 byte data. Also it would be good, if someone could point out any C based implementation of the algorithm?

Comment: Pad plaintext to 16 with two NUL bytes and encrypt that, then strip them after decryption.

Comment: Why not pad it out?

Comment: How often does the data you're encrypting change? I assume it changes more often than the key?

Comment: Also, is your 14 bytes of data fully random, or is it restricted to a smaller set of values (ASCII, decimal digits, etc.)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Such an easy scheme would make it undecryptable, but [ciphertext stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing) might work, but only with DES because CTS needs at least two blocks.

Comment: ^^^^ @ArtjomB., please post that as an answer. I was racking my brain on how to get two blocks for CTS, and duh, use a 64-bit block! You could also use Blowfish in that case, which would be a little nicer than DES.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for the encouragement. I did.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean both plaintext and ciphertext are exactly 14 bytes in length:

Use AES in CTR mode. This yields the same 16 byte chunks of data on each side. You can use 14 of the 16 bytes as an XOR key and discard the last two.

<strike>Initialization of the IV is done with 14 bytes of IV and two bytes of zeros.</strike>

However, there's a wrinkle here. The underlying protocol is stateless broadcast. The only way to get an IV is to use a unique packet identifier, and there might not be one. Without about 10 additional bytes I would have a very hard time coming up with a unique IV generator.

Comment: How would you share the IV, while ensuring that this key+IV is never reused for two different encryptions? I'm struggling to design something to deal with that.

Comment: @RobNapier: IV doesn't have to be secret. You can use a 14 byte counter on the connecting side.

Comment: Yes, but it has to be unique for every message, and that's very difficult with a BLE advertising packet. BLE advertising is 1-way communication, not a 2-way channel where you can negotiate an IV. If the advertised data changes, and you don't change the counter, then CTR is broken. Think of BLE advertising like putting up a billboard by the side of the road and anyone can read it. And it can only be 14 letters long including any metadata to identify this message…

Comment: (I know it doesn't matter for the IV that others can read it, but also you can't know if you've missed any messages. There's no flow control or ACK or anything like that. Just a message you happen to see.)

Comment: @Joshua Can you tell what do you mean by "You can use 14 of the 16 bytes as an XOR key and discard the last two". I am very new in encryption domain, it would be helpful, if you could give some example.

Comment: @RaviGaniga: AES-CTR encrypts a number (counter) and spits out a block of bits. Those bits can be xored into the message. A good exercise is to write a small program that xors two files of the same length together.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ECB-based [Ciphertext Stealing (CTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing) with a block cipher that has a block size smaller than 14 byte. I won't go into detail how CTS works, because the Wikipedia article does a pretty good job.

If you heard that ECB is bad then you are correct. Sadly any other mode requires some sort of IV which will eat away your payload constraint. Since CTS moves a part of the ciphertext to the last plaintext block the bad property of ECB goes away.

Block ciphers with small block sizes such as 64-bit have worse security properties than say block ciphers with 128-bit blocks. Just look at the [Sweet32 attack](https://sweet32.info/). In your case I would guess that this is not really an issue since an attacker cannot get you to generate many many encrypted broadcasts and if they tried it would take them a really long time.

A popular block cipher with 64-bit block size is DES. You might have heard that DES is easily brute forceable due to the small key size and you would be correct. Triple-DES (EEE or EDE) comes to the rescue which has a key size that is three times larger and has a much better protection against brute force attacks.

Sadly, you cannot use AES because CTS needs at least two blocks to work and a single block of AES already breaks your size constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Both AES and DES are Block Cipher algorithms, so you're right that they have minimum sizes for the blocks they can handle. *BUT* there are [many different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) ways to use block encryption, some of which can process streams of data of arbitrary length. Check out "*s*-bit Cipher Feedback Mode" where the *s* is the size of the actual chunks that are individually being encrypted. Here you could use *s*=2.

Answer (score 0):

Why not frame your data so that it features:

1. header
2. payload
3. padding

The header would contain the length of the data, plus maybe a "magic" code to check synchronisation.  The payload is your data.  The padding is then a block of zeroes (or random numbers if you so wish) in order to fit the necessary multiple of blockside for the block-cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to transmit in the same 14 bytes you are a bit stuck. The suggestions above mean that you would need to transmit 16 bytes (or even more), then ignore the last 2 bytes.

How secure do you need the data to be? One answer might be to use DES to encrypt all the full blocks (one block of 8 bytes in your case), then use something weaker to encode the remaining (6 in your case) bytes.
A reasonably secure way would be to simply xor the previous 6-byte decoded byte values over your remaining 6 bytes of tail data. Until the DES protected data has been decoded, the xor value cannot be determined.

Of course, if the DES portion was all-zeros then your tail codes are going to be visible. If this is a rare occurrence this may not be an issue as the hacker does not know that the DES data is zeros. You don't have a lot of data, so it is hard to think of much more that you could do.

In general, you could generate a 64-bit (8-byte) checksum of the previous 1K of original data, and use this as the xor. In general you will have a number less than 8 bytes of tail data, which you would xor, and only transmit the number of bytes. On decode, the remaining bytes are ignored.

Comment: Don't roll your own. Use [ciphertext stealing (CTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing).